# Best way to store a value easily editable by apex

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, visual-workflow

I want to store a text value that I can easily modify using apex. I want to use it to change the behaviour of a visual flow depending of the value in this field.

- I think about custom metadata type but need to use SOAP API to modify it.
- Static resources can only store files if I'm right.
- I found Custom Label can't be modify with DML in apex

If it's not possible, what solution should I use?

Comment: Custom Settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Platform cache either Org cache or Session cache based on your detailed requirement.

Here is an usage:

```
// Get partition
Cache.OrgPartition orgPart = Cache.Org.getPartition('local.CurrencyCache');
// Add cache value to the partition. Usually, the value is obtained from a 
// callout, but hardcoding it in this example for simplicity.
orgPart.put('DollarToEuroRate', '0.91');
// Retrieve cache value from the partition
String cachedRate = (String)orgPart.get('DollarToEuroRate');
```

For more information, refer [Get Started with Platform Cache](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/platform_cache/platform_cache_get_started)